# How to handle endless loop "Sign-in Required" after connecting to sandbox account (iOS 13.1.2)

Tags: ios, xcuitest, uitest

I'm running UiTests using XCUITests framework, and part of my tests is a purchase tests.

Most of the time I get the alert "Sign-in Required" with the text "Enter the password for ."(the dot is part of the real message)! in a loop.

I tried to Enter the previous password/disconnect from the sandbox account/reconnect to another account/restart the device/delete and reinstall the tested app, but nothing works and the alert keep appearing each time I run my app

Screenshot of the alert:
[Link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iriEq.png)

Any idea how can I get rid of this alert for good?

Comment: This is bugging me for days... any updates?

Comment: Sometimes it’s disappears for some time after restart the device,but it’s not a real solution